# Activity error even thought its declared in manifest

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

firsly i want to say i use the 2 Intents i refer in each to change activity between them and i can also move to this class with an intent but when i try to startactivty from this class it crashes .

this is the class where i get the error.

```
    package com.example.wince.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Wince on 31.05.2016.
 */
public class RotaGoster extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    final Intent rotaIntent = new Intent(this, com.example.wince.myapplication.Rota.class);
    final Intent kayitIntent = new Intent(this, com.example.wince.myapplication.RotaKayit.class);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rota);
        String isim = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DB_name");
        VeriTabani VT = new VeriTabani(this);
        Button Kayit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button Rota = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        int i = 0;
        ArrayList<Yer> yerler = new ArrayList<>();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        yerler.addAll(VT.getAllYer());
        for (i = 0; i < yerler.size(); i++) {
            if (yerler.get(i).equals(isim)) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(VT.getYer(i).getLat(), VT.getYer(i).getLng())).title(i + "'inci nokta"));
            }

        }

        Kayit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(kayitIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        Rota.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(rotaIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });


        //dbden verileri çekmek gerek


        // db işlemleri ve gösterim burda yapılıcak.


    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);

    }
}
```

this is the android manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".RotaKayit"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Rota"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".RotaGoster"></activity>
</application>
```

this is the logcat for error

```
06-05 15:51:55.032 10275-10275/com.example.wince.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.wince.myapplication, PID: 10275
                                                                             android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.example.wince.myapplication.Rota}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1636)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1430)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3532)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3493)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3735)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3703)
                                                                                 at com.example.wince.myapplication.RotaGoster$2.onClick(RotaGoster.java:55)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19274)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Other than a clean/rebuild, I don't see a clear solution

Comment: try transforming com.example.wince.myapplication.Rota.class to Rota.class

Comment: what is your package structure?

Comment: @omkomawar it used to be that way saw this solved it for some people it was same with it.

Comment: @omkomawar com.example.wince.myapplication then 6 classes under it

Comment: @cricket_007 thats actualy a good idea will try now :)

Comment: You've only fully qualified the class instead of an import, so it shouldn't really matter which way. It's only cleaner to read with an import

Comment: @cricket_007 nope no luck with clean rebuild still same :/

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah i thought so but i don't see any reason for the exception.

Comment: Okay, then put the full package+class name in the manifest

Comment: @cricket_007   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842) does this mean this is happening on 842

Comment: @cricket_007 na solved it with putting the Intent declaration in the oncreate method dunno what was the problem but its fixed now

Comment: @omkomawar Yes, line 842 of the Android SDK source code... not a problem with the actual app ; +Wince awesome, not sure about that either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the code like this ; putting intent declarations in the oncreate method seems to solve the problem

```
    package com.example.wince.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Wince on 31.05.2016.
 */
public class RotaGoster extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rota);
        String isim = getIntent().getExtras().getString("DB_name");
        VeriTabani VT = new VeriTabani(this);
        Button Kayit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button Rota = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        int i = 0;
        final Intent rotaIntent = new Intent(this, Rota.class);
        final Intent kayitIntent = new Intent(this, RotaKayit.class);
        ArrayList<Yer> yerler = new ArrayList<>();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map2);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        yerler.addAll(VT.getAllYer());
        for (i = 0; i < yerler.size(); i++) {
            if (yerler.get(i).equals(isim)) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(VT.getYer(i).getLat(), VT.getYer(i).getLng())).title(i + "'inci nokta"));
            }

        }

        Kayit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(kayitIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        Rota.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(rotaIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });


        //dbden verileri çekmek gerek


        // db işlemleri ve gösterim burda yapılıcak.


    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a reference to `this` outside of the instance, so you can only declare the Intents as fields, but you must initialize them in `onCreate` or later.

They also don't need to be final.